# Listar dados mysql em um modal usando php

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap, modal

Gostaria de listar um campo que está no banco de dados em uma lista que já está criada. Quando o usuário clicar no campo "título" ele tem que chamar um modal com alguns dados do banco de dados. 
O que ocorre, ele até chama, só que da primeira linha, nas linhas restantes ele retorna os dados contidos na primeira linha. Abaixo segue meu código:

```html
<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data de cadastro</th>
      <th>titulo</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gr_atividade ati
               join gr_entidade ent on ent.id_entidade = ati.id_entidade
               WHERE ati.id_processo = ". $_GET['id']."
               order by data_cadastro desc");
    while ($atividade = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                               
    ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $atividade['data_cadastro']?></td>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h4><?php echo $atividade['titulo']?></h4>
      <p><?php echo $atividade['descricao']?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><?php echo $atividade['titulo']?></a></td>
    <td><?php echo $atividade['nome'].'&nbsp'.$atividade['sobrenome'];
      ?>
    </td>

    
      </td>
   </tr>

     <?php
     }
     ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Da forma atual até funciona somente para a primeira linha, mas para as demais, é repetido o valor da primeira linha , mas somente o modal que é repetido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `id` **deve** ser utilizado apenas em um elemento. A cada novo `modal` você tem que utilizar um `id` diferente.

Quando você utiliza vários `id` iguais, o JavaScript irá capturar o primeiro elemento e desconsiderará os restantes.

Você pode utilizar uma variável, por exemplo `count`, para diferenciar os `models`. Isso gerará `myModal1`, `myModal2`, `myModal3`, `myModal4`

**Exemplo:**

```
<table class="table">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Data de cadastro</th>
      <th>titulo</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        $count = 0;

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gr_atividade ati
                                                            join gr_entidade ent on ent.id_entidade = ati.id_entidade
                                                            WHERE ati.id_processo = ". $_GET['id']."
                                                            order by data_cadastro desc");
                while ($atividade = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                               
                ?>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <?php echo $atividade['data_cadastro']?>
        </td>
        <div id="myModal<?php echo $count ?>" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Heading</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>
                  <?php echo $atividade['titulo']?>
                </h4>
                <p>
                  <?php echo $atividade['descricao']?>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div>
        <td>
          <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $count++ ?>">
            <?php echo $atividade['titulo']?>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $atividade['nome'].'&nbsp'.$atividade['sobrenome'];
                        ?>
        </td>

      </tr>

      <?php } ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: A sua resposta faz todo sentido. Muito obrigado amigo !